# Length of a json value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string-length

**Given data such :**

```
var json = [ 
  { "id": "A", "status":   1, "rank": 30,  "score": 0.1  },
  { "id": "B", "status":   1, "rank": 30,  "score": 0.7  },
  { "id": "C", "status":   1, "rank": 60,  "score": 0.8  },
  { "id": "AB", "status":  1, "rank": 160, "score": 0.6  },
  { "id": "ABC", "status": 1, "rank": 400, "score": 0.2 }
];
```

**How to get the id's length ?**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RBSC9/

---

The following doesn't works:

```
var l = (json[3].id).text().length();
console.log("l = "+ l );
```

Comment: You're asking how to get the length of a string???

Comment: Yes... Was a typo mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *.lenght

```
var l = json[3].id.length;
console.log("length["+json[3].id+"] = "+ l );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RBSC9/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var len = json[3].id.length;
console.log("len = "+ len);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the update fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/RBSC9/3/

```
var l = (json[3].id).length
```

You want to mention `length` like `length;` not `length();`